# Text over image in css with variable position

Tags: html, css

I have a set of divs (11 of them), 8 of them with an image and 3 of them with ':'.

[image]

all 11 boxes are inside a class "timer".
Something like this:

```
<div class="timer">
  <div><img></div>
  <div><img></div>
  <div>:</div>
</div>
```

I added text over image by using p tags inside each div and using this code on css:

```
.text{
position: absolute;
left: 85px;
top: 185px;
}
```

But on resisizing the window, the boxes move but the text stays. How can I make the text move along with the boxes?

Comment: Sounds like you forgot `position:Relative` somewhere. - Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you use bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/ you can use a custom set of classes that make your page far more responsive very easily. Here is a tutorial guide... http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1):

Missing a few things here:

```
<div>:</div>
```

should actually be:

```
<div class="text">:</div>
```

if you want to apply your CSS that's targeting .text to this div containing the `:`.

Also if you want the container to hold the absolutely positioned element, you need to set your timer to be relative position:

```
.timer { position: relative; }
```